# Нужно создать интерактивные графики python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Подскажите интерактивные графики, которые могут служить заменой для broken barh matplotlib?  График получается большой и очень мелкие буквы, хочу сделать всплывающее окно с текстом, когда наводишь на график.
[image: Диаграмма Ганта]

Приведен пример кода:

```
    gnt.broken_barh([(start1 , timedelta(hours=7))], (i*10+2.5, 5), facecolors ='tab:blue')
    start1 += timedelta(hours=10)
```

Comment: А если взять `plotly`, например? Там вроде зум был встроенный и всякая такая интерактивность. А вообще показали бы примерный вид графика, может имеет смысл вообще как-то по-другому сделать.

Comment: График имеет вид диаграммы ганта